# Php array find same value inside foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [influencer_user_id] => 4
        [content_data] => {"Reach":"300","Views":"320","Views through rate":"350","Shares":"350"}
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [influencer_user_id] => 4
        [content_data] => {"Reach":"100","Likes":"100","Views":"100"}
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [influencer_user_id] => 5
        [content_data] => {"Reach":"350"}
    )

)


foreach($influencer_contents as $row){
      $influencer_id = $row['influencer_user_id'];
}
```

if influencer_user_id is same inside the loop I need to sum the content_data.
given example there are 3 array values influencer_user_id has to 4, I need to merge first two arrays( has same values) and need to make array count 2.

I tried like I created temporary array and I pushed the same influencer_id to temp_array like below but that is not working

```
if(!in_array($influencer_id, $array_temp)){
          $array_temp[] = $influencer_id;  }
```

i need output like this below,

```
Array
 (

[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [influencer_user_id] => 4
        [content_data] => {"Reach":"400","Likes":"100","Views":"100"}
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [influencer_user_id] => 5
        [content_data] => {"Reach":"350"}
    )

  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the solution you're looking?

```
<?php

$data = [
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "influencer_user_id" => 4,
        "content_data" => '{"Reach":"300","Views":"320","Views through rate":"350","Shares":"350"}',
    ],
    [
        "id" => 2,
        "influencer_user_id" => 4,
        "content_data" => '{"Reach":"100","Likes":"100","Views":"100"}',
    ],
    [
        "id" => 3,
        "influencer_user_id" => 5,
        "content_data" => '{"Reach":"350"}',
    ],
]; 

$result = array();

// first, group the influencer_user_id
foreach ($data as $element) {
    $result[$element['influencer_user_id']][] = $element;
}

// second, calculate content_data
$result = array_map(function($element){
    $element = array_reduce($element, function($carry, $item){

        // convert to array
        $content_data = json_decode($item['content_data'], true);

        // convert content_data to integer values
        $content_data = array_map('intval', $content_data);

        $item['content_data'] = $content_data;

        if(empty($carry))
            return $item;

        // compute content_data sum
        array_walk($item['content_data'], function(&$value, $key) use ($carry){
            if(isset($carry['content_data'][$key])){
                $value += $carry['content_data'][$key];
            }
        });

        return $item;
    });

    // convert content_data back to json
    $cdata = $element['content_data'];
    $element['content_data'] = json_encode($cdata);

    return $element;
}, $result);

$result = array_values($result);

print_r($result);
```

The output to this is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [influencer_user_id] => 4
            [content_data] => {"Reach":400,"Likes":100,"Views":420}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [influencer_user_id] => 5
            [content_data] => {"Reach":350}
        )

)
```

Here is the link to my solution: https://3v4l.org/1aETf

Comment: seriously awesome!. Jim.B thank you so much it's working fine.

Comment: Very well explained.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```
<?php

$data = 
array
(
    '0' => array
        (
            'id' => 1,
            'influencer_user_id' => 4,
            'content_data' => '{"Reach":"300","Views":"320","Views through rate":"350","Shares":"350"}'
        ),
    '1' => array
        (
            'id' => 2,
            'influencer_user_id' => 4,
            'content_data' => '{"Reach":"100","Likes":"100","Views":"100"}'
        ),
    '2' => array
        (
            'id' => 3,
            'influencer_user_id' => 5,
            'content_data' => '{"Reach":"350"}'
        )
);
```

Method:

```
// Group influencer data
foreach($data as $item) {
    $item['content_data'] = json_decode($item['content_data'], true);
    $result[$item['influencer_user_id']][] = $item;
}

// Merge influencer data, and sum respective content_data
foreach($result as &$item) {
    $item = array_merge_recursive(...$item);
    // Use last occuring ids.
    foreach(['id', 'influencer_user_id'] as $key)
        if(is_array($item[$key]))
            $item[$key] = array_pop($item[$key]);
    // Sum content_data keys
    foreach($item['content_data'] as &$v)
        if(is_array($v))
            $v = (string) array_sum($v);
    unset($v);
    $item['content_data'] = json_encode($item['content_data']);
}
unset($item);

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
    4 => 
    array (
      'id' => 2,
      'influencer_user_id' => 4,
      'content_data' => '{"Reach":"400","Views":"420","Views through rate":"350","Shares":"350","Likes":"100"}',
    ),
    5 => 
    array (
      'id' => 3,
      'influencer_user_id' => 5,
      'content_data' => '{"Reach":"350"}',
    ),
  )
```

This method leans on [array_merge_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php), example:

```
var_export(array_merge_recursive(
    ['bert' => ['paperclips' => 10]],
    ['bert' => ['paperclips' => 5, 'duckys' => 2]]
));
```

Output:

```
array (
    'bert' => 
    array (
      'paperclips' => 
      array (
        0 => 10,
        1 => 5,
      ),
      'duckys' => 2,
    ),
  )
```